# Usar duas ou mais vezes While para um mesmo Select?

Tags: php, mysql, query

Estou montando uma página de listagem e cadastro de saída de produtos e estou tendo problema na hora de puxar as informações e fazer o *while* pela segunda vez.

Exemplo:

```
$sql_for = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM cliente ORDER BY cli_nome ASC");
$sql_for2 = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE cli_status='on');
```

Aqui mostra a lista em uma tabela:

```
while($linha_for = mysql_fetch_object($sql_for)){
    echo $linha_for->cli_nome;
}
```

Aqui seria pra mostrar dentro de um *select option* com todos os clientes

```
while($linha_for = mysql_fetch_object($sql_for)){
   echo $linha_for->cli_nome;
}
```

Aqui seria pra mostrar dentro de um *select option* e aqui somente os clientes ativos

```
while($linha_for2 = mysql_fetch_object($sql_for2)){
   echo $linha_for2->cli_nome;
}
```

Agora vem o problema: a ideia era fazer outro *while* aproveitando a *query* já existente e puxar o dados do cliente pelo `id`, mas não consegui achar um esquema de fazer uma função. Ela repete os dados obtido na primeira *query*. Não consegui filtrar as informações.

Segue o código que encontrei:

```
function listarTodosClientes($db){
   $sql = 'select * from cliente';
   $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

   $lista = array();
   while($item = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
      $lista[] = $item;
   }

  return $lista;
}
```

Para usar:

```
//$clientes tem os dados do banco, chame ele onde precisar agora.    
$clientes = listarTodosClientes($db);

foreach($clientes as $item){
   echo $item['cli_nome'] . '<br>';
}
echo "--------------------- <br>"; 

foreach($clientes as $item){
   echo $item['cli_nome'] . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Obter os dados do cliente? mas esses não estão já na tabela clientes?

Comment: Uma observação, a segunda consulta está com um erro de digitação, `$sql_for2 = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE cli_status='on');` está faltando o fechamento das aspas duplas **"**. `$sql_for2 = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE cli_status='on'");`

Answer (score 1):

Se eu entendi bem você quer algo do tipo

```
function listarTodosClientes($db,$id=0){
    $sql = 'select * from cliente';
    if(!empty($id)){
        $sql.= " WHERE cli_id  = ".$id;
    }
    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    $lista = array();
    while($item = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
       $lista[] = $item;
   }

    return $lista;
}
```

Uma peguena observação estes métodos **mysql_query** e **mysql_error** [estão deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php)